# How can I render a custom values on specific column of Vuetify table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to display `rules` `>` `details` count in one of the column called `conditions`.

***Note:***

> rules is an array, where rules.details.length = 2

## I tried

[image]

*code*

```
headers: [
    { text: 'Priority', value: 'priority', width: '10%' },
    {
        text: 'Name',
        align: 'start',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name',
        width: '30%'
    },
    { text: 'URL', value: 'url', width: '30%' },
    { text: 'Condition', value: '?????????', width: '20%' },
    { text: '', value: 'data-table-expand', width: '5%' }
],
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using `computed` to get new items with the property you need. You can change the property to whatever you need.

Or you can use `v-slot:item.conditions` like the example on the page of the link.
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-data-table/slot-simple-checkbox.vue

The link is from here
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#simple-checkbox

Comment: I think your Codepen link is broken

Comment: It's not showing anything at all.

Comment: I think the link is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

Observations/Suggestions **:**

- As we use `headers` array to show the column names. You should not assign any dynamic value in that. Instead you can do this in the column data.
- You can achieve this requirement by adding the condition value in `mounted` lifecycle hook.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: "Priority", value: 'priority' },
      { text: "Name", value: 'name' },
      { text: "URL", value: 'url' },
      { text: "Condition", value: 'condition' }
    ],
      rules: [{
      priority: 1,
      name: "Alpha",
      url: 'https://example.com',
      urlGroup: '',
      condition: ''
    }, {
      priority: 2,
      name: "Beta",
      url: 'https://example.com',
      urlGroup: 'userGroup2',
      condition: ''
    }],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const rulesLength = this.rules.length;
    this.rules.forEach((obj) => {
        obj.condition = rulesLength;
    })
  },
  methods: {
    displayURLInfo(index) {
      if (this.rules[index].urlGroup != '') {
         return      this.rules[index].urlGroup
      } else {
        return this.rules[index].url
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="rules"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.url="{ index, item }">
    {{ displayURLInfo(index) }}
</template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```